# Tabbed menu - If list item is active, display page excerpt in extra `div` next to child menu

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a dropdown menu that contains WP pages made to work as tabs. - https://www.zzpstart.nl/

If you click on "Bankzaken" on the left hand side on the right side, you'll get `ul` children menu items displayed, which is working super well! However, next to it in the "home promo `div`", I'd like to get a page excerpt of the parent page "Bankzaken" with a link to that page. I hope this is clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear from your question exactly what you want to achieve. Can you not take screenshots of the page in question, store those images in a hidden `preload` div and populate the "home Promo" `div` with the applicable image? Is this what you want or are you trying to request the chosen page and place its HTML contents into the "Home Promo" `div`? Please add code snippet(s) for the relevant menu items and "Home Promo" preview `div`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make the bankzaken, belasting and network tabs at the left side static.

Then add menu locations for the static items like this:

```
add_action('init', 'zzp_register_menus');
function zzp_register_menus()
{
  register_nav_menu('bankzaken-menu', __('Bankzaken Menu'));
  register_nav_menu('belasting-menu', __('Belasting Menu'));
}
```

In WordPress, you can then create menu's for these locations (bankzaken, belasting, enz)

To obtain the items by the location, use the following function:

```
/**
 * Get nav menu items by location
 *
 * @param $location The menu location id
 */
function get_nav_menu_items_by_location( $location, $args = [] ) {

    // Get all locations
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

    // Get object id by location
    $object = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[$location] );

    // Get menu items by menu name
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $object->name, $args );

    // Return menu post objects
    return $menu_items;
}
```

Javascript might be a good idea to check wich tab is active.

I hope this helps, let me know

Comment: Hi @Napinator in header file inside dropdown I just simply call get_sidebar which is widget with wp pages listed.. then with js I made that work as tabs. and next to that I thought to have that box where I can display page excerpt based on active parent link inside that tabs menu. And yes, I dont know how to use this piece of code you sent :(
Hope this is helpful

Comment: ing.nl has similar menu but it's static I think.
If you open "Producten" dropdown you'll see tabs menu and on the right side one extra box with Title, image, text.. if you navigate trough tabs on left hand side you will see that content in that extra box on right side is changing. 
That's what I want, only to get that content dynamic from wp page excerpt, or post.

Comment: Did you fix it yet? let me know, i'll dive in to it and will provide the code for you

Comment: not :( Thanks mate!!
ps. One option would be to not pull page excerpt but static blocks.. so each tab has one static block that will be displayed in promo div if tab is active.

Comment: can i use a submenu for this?
so prodcuten => bankzaken => list of subitems of bankzaken.

Comment: Thats how it works actually - If you click on Bankzaken you get subitems listed.. but then in Promo div we have to list something else.. page excerpt or some static content related to Bankzaken (parent active menu item).. or if Belasting is active parent then content related to that.. etc.

Comment: what do you think - can one option be js - if it's parent link .active then show something in that promo div?